# How to intercept code in rx-netty's thread pool

Tags: httpclient, netty, rx-netty

I have data stored in ThreadLocal (such as MDC) and I need it to update it for each request.

Using the rx-netty http client I put the value as a http header but I can't find a hook where I can read this value after the control is passed into the netty thread pool and then set it on the thread local of the netty thread.

Is this possible using some API?

Answer (score 1):

You can add netty's `ChannelHandler` using RxNetty's `PipelineConfigurator`(somewhat like this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxNetty/blob/0.4.x/rxnetty-examples/src/main/java/io/reactivex/netty/examples/tcp/cpuintensive/CPUIntensiveServer.java#L66). Then your code will be executed in Netty's eventloop. 
Once you have a sample code, I can look into it, in case you need more help.

Comment: @nitest-kant Thanks. Can you elaborate more? Currently I see that the builder uses this:
withPipelineConfigurator(DEFAULT_HTTP_PIPELINE_CONFIGURATOR)

How exactly do I add a Channel Handler?

Also, Channel Handler is set an client build time and I need a hook to set a value on the caller thread that will be available when this handler is run in the netty thread and repeat that logic for each http request.

Comment: @YaOg Here is a gist that demonstrates how to add a handler and read HTTP headers in that handler:

https://gist.github.com/NiteshKant/5202f396ac903d2dc0a4

The handlers are executed in Netty's eventloop for every write (which in this case is for each request).

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but now the same request running against the same server fails on timeout.